# Can Hadoop MultipleInputs.addInputPath be made to work recursively?

Tags: hadoop, emr

Recent versions of Hadoop already easily support nested input directories using `FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive`, which relies on the `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive` configuration key.

It's also possible to specify multiple mapper/input-directory combinations using `MultipleInputs.addInputPath`.

But can I do both at the same time? In other words, is there a way specify multiple mapper/input-directory combinations where the input directories are included recursively?

A concrete example:
I have the following directory structure:

- `/dataset1/subdir1/data1.txt`
- `/dataset2/subdir2/data2.txt`

I tried something like this:

```
Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path("/dataset1"), TextInputFormat.class,
    Mapper1.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path("/dataset2"), TextInputFormat.class,
    Mapper2.class);
...
job.waitForCompletion(true);
```

But then I get an exception along the lines of `Error: java.io.IOException: 's3://bucketname/dataset1/subdir1' is a directory`

This is running in Amazon EMR under Hadoop 2.4.0.

*Edit: Hadoop version is 2.4.0, not 2.6.0*

Answer (score 1):

Well, Not sure about s3, but this is normal. Should point to **file** and not a directory.

Try this.

**Method 1**

```
final static public void addInputPathRecursively(FileSystem fs, Path path, PathFilter inputFilter, Job job,boolean swithc) throws IOException
        {
            for (FileStatus stat : fs.listStatus(path, inputFilter))
            {
                if (stat.isDirectory())
                {

                    addInputPathRecursively(fs, stat.getPath(), inputFilter, job);
                } else
                {
                    if (swithc)
                    {
                        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(stat.getPath().toString()), TextInputFormat.class, Mapper1.class);

                    } else
                        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(stat.getPath().toString()), TextInputFormat.class, Mapper2.class);
                }
            }
        }
```

In the driver class you can call it accordingly.

```
addInputPathRecursively(fs, datset1path, new FileFilter(conf, fs,
                        new String[] { txt }), job,true);

addInputPathRecursively(fs, datset2path, new FileFilter(conf, fs,
                        new String[] { txt }), job,false);
```

This is an example but working control the pathfilter properly if you want to apply regEx.

- **Method 2**
  Setting this should do the magic too.

  FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);
- **Method 3**
  Bypass inside the mapper and process at line level. (Not a good idea!)